# Convergence in probability iff convergence for every bounded continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, recreational-mathematics

I'm trying to show the following:

$X_n \overset{p}{\to}X \iff f \circ X_n \overset{p}{\to} f \circ X$ for every continuous, bounded function $f$.

I can show ($\Rightarrow$) already using the usual almost-everywhere converging subsequences approach.  The other direction is giving me difficulty.

I believe I can show it if $f$ is strictly increasing: then $f$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ onto some interval $(a,b)$, thus $f^{-1}$ is continuous, so it suffices to apply the continuous function $f^{-1}$ to $f\circ X_n$.  (Though if this is incorrect please do let me know.)

For the general case, however, I'm not quite sure how to proceed.  My two questions are:

1) How to show $(\Leftarrow)$ when I can't rely on $f$ being strictly monotone?

2) What is the intuition behind needing $f$ to be bounded?  I feel like this should be obvious but I can't seem to intuit why.

Many thanks.

**Disclaimer:** I'm pursuing self-study in Cinlar's 'Probability and Stochastics' in my spare time, this is problem 3.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and $r>0$. We want to show

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| \geq r) \leq \epsilon \qquad \text{for all $n$ sufficiently large.}$$

Set

$$\chi_R(x) := (-R) \vee x \wedge R = \begin{cases} R, & x \geq R, \\ x, & x \in [-R,R] \\ -R,, & x \leq -R \end{cases}.$$

Obviously, $\chi_R$ is bounded and continuous. Moreover, as $\chi_R(x)=x$ for all $|x| \leq R$, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| \geq r) \leq \mathbb{P}(|\chi_R(X_n)-\chi_R(X)| \geq r) + \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq R) + \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq R).$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq R)
&= \mathbb{P}\left(|X_n| \geq R, |X| \leq \frac{R}{2} \right) + \mathbb{P} \left(|X|> \frac{R}{2} \right) \\
&\leq \mathbb{P} \left( |\chi_R(X_n)| \geq R, |\chi_R(X)|=|X| \leq \frac{R}{2} \right) + \mathbb{P} \left(| X|> \frac{R}{2} \right) \\
&\leq \mathbb{P} \left( |\chi_R(X_n)-\chi_R(X)| \geq \frac{R}{2} \right) + \mathbb{P} \left(| X|> \frac{R}{2} \right) \end{align*}$$

Combining both estimates, we obtain

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| \geq r) &\leq \mathbb{P}(|\chi_R(X_n)-\chi_R(X)| \geq r)+ \mathbb{P}\left(|\chi_R(X_n)-\chi_R(X)| \geq \frac{R}{2} \right) \\ &\quad + \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq R) + \mathbb{P} \left(| X|> \frac{R}{2} \right) \end{align*}$$

Choose $R$ sufficiently large such that

$$\mathbb{P} \left(| X|> \frac{R}{2} \right) \leq \epsilon$$

For this (fixed!) $R$, it follows from our assumption that we can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ \mathbb{P}(|\chi_R(X_n)-\chi_R(X)| \geq r)+ \mathbb{P}\left(|\chi_R(X_n)-\chi_R(X)| \geq \frac{R}{2} \right) \leq \epsilon$$

for all $n \geq N$. Adding all up, we get

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| \geq r)  \leq 3 \epsilon$$

for all $n \geq N$.

Concerning boundedness: The boundedness of $f$ is not needed. Obviously, the equivalence holds also if we drop the assumption "bounded" (however, then "$\Leftarrow$" is obvious.)

Comment: Thank you for that.  So really what it comes down to is that if it is true for all such functions, then it must be true for your chi, which is sufficient for the result?

Comment: Upon further thought, if the above is true, then I could make an alternative proof using the Ky Fan metric? 

Let $d(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}(|X-Y|\wedge 1)$.  Thus if $f\circ X_n \to f \circ X$ for all continuous bounded $f$ then $d(X_n, 0) \to d(X,0) \Rightarrow d(|X_n-X|,0) \to 0$ which in turn implies $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability?

Comment: @see.blue Yes, it suffices to have statement for all $\chi_R$, $R>0$. Concerning your second question: How do you choose $f$ to conclude $d(X_n,0) \to d(X,0)$?

Comment: I was thinking to choose $f(\cdot)=d(\cdot,0)$ which is continuous and bounded (as $X$, $Y$ are RVs), but I clearly can't get the implication $d(X_n,0)→d(X,0)⇒d(|X_n−X|,0)$ from that so it was an incorrect thought.  Haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @see.blue Actually, I had the same idea ... in some sense that's exactly the idea of my proof. The function $\chi_R$ satisfies $$|\chi_R(X_n)-\chi_R(X)| = |X_n-X|$$ whenever $|X_n|,|X| \leq R$. Now, $$d(X,X_n) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X_n-X| 1_{\{|X_n|,|X| \leq R}\}) + \mathbb{P}(\{|X_n| \geq R\} \cup \{|X| \geq R\}).$$

Comment: Yeah, precisely.  I enjoyed your proof because I think it was particularly illuminating to see the epsilonics done out.  In terms of arriving at the shortest proof then, ultimately the result for strictly increasing $f$ and  "$\Rightarrow$" then suffices as well?  

Something along the lines of:  
$f \circ X_n \overset{p}{\to} f \circ X$ for all bounded continuous $f$ implies convergence for str. incr. $f$. Any such str. incr. $f$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ onto $(a,b)$, thus $f^{-1}$ cont. thus the result follows from "$\Rightarrow$" using $f^{-1}$ as our continuous function.

Comment: @see.blue Yeah, sounds correct.